# Increment and use reactive ref inside v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I am trying to display two separate arrays using Vue's for loop.
Both arrays hold 0-n strings, and I want to display a maximum of 3 strings, both arrays combined.

Meaning:

Scenario 1: if both array1 and array2 each hold 2 strings, array1's strings and the first string of array2 should be rendered (in different parts of the template!).

Scenario 2: array1 holds 5 strings, array2 3 strings. array1 has priority and its first 3 strings will be rendered, no string of array2 will be rendered.

**Important Note**: I need to render those strings separately in different divs, which makes slicing the arrays

To make this work I thought of using a ref which I would increment on every looped item and in every loop check whether the refs value is lower than 3; if not "break" the loop. Thought this sounded simple enough but I am currently at a loss. It does not render anything but it seems to count up to 3.

**Not** working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-tharp-32vxm3?file=/src/App.vue

Heres my code:

```js
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in arr1" :key="index">
    <template v-if="currentlyRenderedItems < 3">
      {{ item }}
      <!-- count right here? -->
      {{ currentlyRenderedItems++ }}
    </template>
  </div>

  <div>Some other stuff happening here!</div>

  <div v-for="(item, index) in arr2" :key="index">
    <template v-if="currentlyRenderedItems < 3">
      {{ item }}
      <!-- count right here? -->
      {{ currentlyRenderedItems++ }}
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const arr1 = ["what", "is"];
const arr2 = ["going", "on"];

const currentlyRenderedItems = ref(0);
</script>
```

Not sure what is going on; is it just that somehow vue counts first before looping/rendering the items? Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a computed property and render those:

```
const visibleItems = computed(() => [...arr1,...arr2].slice(0,3))
```

You can build the combined array in the `v-for` as well:

```html
<div
  v-for="(item, index) in [...arr1,...arr2].slice(0,3)"
  :key="index"
>
 ...
</div>
```

---

If you need them separately, the easiest solution is probably to use two computeds:

```
const visibleItems1 = computed(() => arr1.slice(0, 3))
const visibleItems2 = computed(() => arr2.slice(0, Math.max(0, 3 - arr1.length)))
```

Similarly, you can do it in the template, but there is a point where it becomes hard to read:

```html
  <div v-for="(item, index) in arr1.slice(0,3)" :key="index">
   ...
  </div>

  <div v-for="(item, index) in arr2.slice(0, Math.max(0, 3 - arr1.length))" :key="index">
    ...
  </div>
```

Comment: Nice answer! Unfortunately I need both parts rendered separately inside different div containers; I will add this to my description.

Comment: Right, I could have seen that in your template, sorry! Check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks again, very sleek solution. Probably I won't be able to use computed since my 2 loops are inside another loop; also should have added that, sorry. Cheers!